# Application A accessing a textfile stored in Application B's Internal Memory

Tags: android

My app (App A) need to write a textfile which will be stored under another app's(App B) internal memory. Any idea how to implement this?

I have tried the following:

Under both the AndroidManifest.xml file, I have specified the same android:sharedUserId.

From App A, I used:

filePath = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("packagename of App B", 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;

to get the path and I have confirmed that the path is correct for App B's internal memory.

But I am getting "java.io.IOException: Permission Denied".

Any idea where I have made mistake?

Comment: You cant access files of another applications in internal storage

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html),

> Technically, another app can read your internal files if you set the file mode to be readable. However, the other app would also need to know your app package name and file names.

It's a do-able thing.

So, create a File object with your filepath and call [setReadable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean%29) on it.

Also, check you're **not** creating the file with MODE_PRIVATE.

Comment: You only can if the files are not PRIVATE.

Comment: true, the documentation also states this _So as long as you use MODE_PRIVATE for your files on the internal storage, they are never accessible to other apps._